# Json single Object check to see if it has duplicate values typescript angular

Tags: javascript, json, object

This might be easy but I am struggling with this at the moment. I need to check inside a function if the there are duplicate values in the json object.

**My Object :-**

```
"controls": {
        "score": "AppId",
        "title": "CountryCode",
        "onesubtitle": "CountryName",
        "twosubtitle": "Region",
        "summary": "CountryHead",
        "keyword": "Region"
    }

 Object.values(this.controls).forEach(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
```

I need to check and return boolean if the values are duplicate in the object like the values bold below.

"controls": {
"score": "AppId",
"title": "CountryCode",
"subtitle1": "CountryName",
"subtitle2": "**Region**",
"summary": "CountryHead",
"keywords": "**Region**"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperative paradigm :

```
let complexObject= {
        "score": "AppId",
        "title": "CountryCode",
        "onesubtitle": "CountryHead1",
        "twosubtitle": "Region",
        "summary": "CountryHead1",
        "keyword": "Region"
    }
let valueArray=[];
Object.values(complexObject).forEach(val => {
      valueArray.push(val)
    });
for(i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {  
    for(j = i + 1; j < valueArray.length; j++) {  
        if(valueArray[i] == valueArray[j])  
            console.log(valueArray[i]); 
    }  
}
```

Declarative paradigm :

```
let complexObject= {
        "score": "AppId",
        "title": "CountryCode",
        "onesubtitle": "CountryHead1",
        "twosubtitle": "Region",
        "summary": "CountryHead1",
        "keyword": "Region"
    }
let valueArray=[];
Object.values(complexObject).forEach(val => {
      valueArray.push(val)
    });

console.log(valueArray.filter((item, index) => valueArray.indexOf(item) !== index));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. we have manipulated the code according to our needs the solution has worked very well. @farazjalili

Comment: The second one could be simplified even further, because `filter` function parameter has 3 parameters `(value, index, array)`, so we don't need to build the `valueArray`. It could just be: `Object.values(complexObject).filter((val, i, a) => a.indexOf(val) !== i)`